# 2 bytes represent 3 integers in C

Tags: c

I have two bytes, 8 bit octets, which should be read as: [3 bits][4 bits][3 bits].

Example:

```
unsigned char octet1 = 0b11111111;  // binary values
unsigned char octet2 = 0b00000011;
```

As integers: [7][15][7].

Anybody can give me a hint where to start?

Comment: ...where to start *what*?

Comment: Homework? Nothing wrong with homework, but questions should be flagged as such. It helps the community to better pitch their answers to be most helpful.

Comment: Now that I'm thiking about it... 3+4+3 != 8 ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the responders, just to clarify: I'm not asking anybody to do any 'homework' for me. I'm just a beginner who tries to understand how such a sequence being parsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to put the two bytes together before extracting bits we want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    unsigned char octet1 = 0b11111111;
    unsigned char octet2 = 0b00000011;
    unsigned char n1 = octet1 & 0b111;
    unsigned char n2 = (octet1 >> 3) & 0b1111;
    unsigned char n3 = (octet1 >> 7) | (octet2 + octet2);

    printf("octet1=%u octet2=%u n1=%u n2=%u n3=%u\n",
              octet1, octet2, n1, n2, n3);

}
```

Comment: Nice way to not having to combine the octets as a word. I think I would have written `(octet2 + octet2)` as `octet2<<2` though. Also this seems to only work if the higher bits of `octet2` always is 0. It might be best to `& 0b111` the last expression to save oneself from future troubles.

Comment: Thanks a lot, to me it seems like the most straight-forward approach. But unfortunately I didn't manage to 'fix' the issue Jonas raised, where the higher bits are not 0. I've tried: n3 = (octet1 >> 7) | (octet2 << 2); ? - I think it was supposed to be <<1, instead of <<2?

Comment: `unsigned char n3 = (octet1>>7 | octet2<<1) & 0b111;`

Comment: Yes, correct `octet2<<2` was wrong because that is the same as `octet2*4`. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks once again! - just to clarify for beginners like myself: the "0b" suffix is not supported by all compilers/versions, so one should use 0x suffix instead. 0b11111111 = 0xFF , and so on...

Answer (score 9):

In a kind of [pseudocode](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Fixnum.html#M001072)

```
octet1 = 0b11111111
octet2 = 0b00000011
word = octet1 | octet2<<8
n1 = word & 0b111
n2 = word>>3 & 0b1111
n3 = word>>7 & 0b111
```

Comment: You might want to add parentheses for clarity.  If your pseudocode is like C, then shifting does have higher precedence than `&` and `|`, but not everyone knows that.

Comment: I'm not so sure it can be called pseudocode at all because it's Ruby. Ruby has the same higher precedence for `>>` to `&` and `|` as C. I think that it shouldn't be necessary to know that `|` is bitwise or, `&` is bitwise and, and that `>>` and `<<` bit shifts right and left to read pseudocode. As a pseudocode example for a C-programmer it might just work.

Comment: Thanks for your sample, your answer received the highest amount of votes - but frankly I think it would be more appropriate to select the one which actually is a C sample, and doesn't require the 3rd assignment of 'word'

Comment: I agree but this was only ment to educate, to show the concept, not to demonstrate the most efficient solution. Anyhow you should consider accepting the answer you liked best.

Answer (score 4):

Hi here is a method that is tested and compiled using VC++9

```
#pragma pack( 1 )

union 
{
    struct 
    {
        unsigned short val1:3;
        unsigned short val2:4;
        unsigned short val3:3; 
        unsigned short val4:6; 
    } vals;
    struct 
    {
        unsigned char octet1:8;
        unsigned char octet2:8;
    } octets;
    short oneVal;
} u = {0xFFFF};

unsigned char octet1 = 0xFF;  //1 1111 111
unsigned char octet2 = 0x03;  //000000 11
//000000 111 1111 111 0 7 15 7
u.octets.octet1 = octet1;
u.octets.octet2 = octet2;
cout << "size of u.vals:" << sizeof(u.vals)<< endl;
cout << "size of u.octets:" << sizeof(u.octets)<< endl;
cout << "size of u.oneVal:" << sizeof(u.oneVal)<< endl;
cout << "size of u:" << sizeof(u)<< endl;
cout << endl;

cout << "Your values:" << endl;
cout << "oneVal in Hex: 0x";
cout.fill( '0' );
cout.width( 4 );
cout<< hex << uppercase << u.oneVal << endl;
cout << "val1: " << (int)u.vals.val1 << endl;
cout << "val2: " << (int)u.vals.val2 << endl;
cout << "val3: " << (int)u.vals.val3 << endl;
cout << "val4: " << (int)u.vals.val4 << endl;
cout << endl;

octet1 = 0xCC;  //1 1001 100
octet2 = 0xFA;  //111110 10
//111110 101 1001 100 62 5 9 4
u.octets.octet1 = octet1;
u.octets.octet2 = octet2;

cout << "Some other values:" << endl;
cout << "oneVal in Hex: 0x";
cout.fill( '0' );
cout.width( 4 );
cout<< hex << uppercase << u.oneVal << endl;
cout << dec;
cout << "val1: " << (int)u.vals.val1 << endl;
cout << "val2: " << (int)u.vals.val2 << endl;
cout << "val3: " << (int)u.vals.val3 << endl;
cout << "val4: " << (int)u.vals.val4 << endl;
cout << endl;

octet1 = 0xCC;  //1 1001 100
octet2 = 0xFA;  //111110 10
//111110 101 1001 100 62 5 9 4
u.oneVal = ( (( unsigned short )octet2 ) << 8 ) | ( unsigned short )octet1;
cout << "Some thing diffrent asignment:" << endl;
cout << "oneVal in Hex: 0x";
cout.fill( '0' );
cout.width( 4 );
cout<< hex << uppercase << u.oneVal << endl;
cout << dec;
cout << "val1: " << (int)u.vals.val1 << endl;
cout << "val2: " << (int)u.vals.val2 << endl;
cout << "val3: " << (int)u.vals.val3 << endl;
cout << "val4: " << (int)u.vals.val4 << endl;
cout << endl;
```

Also note that I uses **#pragma pack( 1 )** to set the structure packing to 1 byte.

I also included a way of assigning the two octets into the one short value.  Did this using bitwise shift "<<" and bitwise or "|"

You can simplify the access to u by dropping the named structures. But I wanted to show the sizes that is used for the structures.

Like this:

```
union 
{
    struct 
    {
        unsigned short val1:3;
        unsigned short val2:4;
        unsigned short val3:3; 
        unsigned short val4:6; 
    };
    struct 
    {
        unsigned char octet1:8;
        unsigned char octet2:8;
    };
    short oneVal;
} u = {0xFFFF};
```

Access would now be as simple as

```
u.oneVal = 0xFACC;
```

or

```
u.octet1 = 0xCC;
u.octet2 = 0xFA;
```

you can also drop either oneVal or octet1 and octet2 depending on what access method you like.

Comment: You know your tired when `Did this using bitwise shit` makes you giggle.

Comment: @Jonas thanks for the spot.  Fixed it should be "Did this using bitwise shift" :).

Comment: Yes, this is the most obvious way to do it in C (for someone who reads the code anyway).

Answer (score 3):

```
  oct2|  oct1
000011|1 1111 111
    ---- ---- ---
     7   0xf   7
```

Just a hint,(assuming it is homework)

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: 0x11111111 doesn't mean 8 bits all set to 1. It's an hexadecimal number of 4 bytes, where any byte is set to 0x11.

0xFF is a single byte (8 bit) where any bit is set to 1.

Then, to achieve what you want you could use some MACROs to isolate the bits you need:

```
#define TOKEN1(x)  ((x)>>7)
#define TOKEN2(x)  ( ((x)>>3) & (0xFF>>5) )
#define TOKEN3(x)  ( ((x)>>5) & (0xFF>>5) )
```

*Didn't test it.*

Another idea, could be that of putting in an union a char and a struct using bitfield chars

```
union {
    struct { char a:3; char b:4; char c:3; };
    char x;
};
```

This way you can use x to edit the whole octet, and a, b and c to access to the single tokens...

**Edit**: 3+4+3 != 8.

If you need 10 bits you should use a short instead of a char. If, instead, some of those bits are overlapping, the solution using MACRO will probably be easier: you'll need more than one struct inside the union to achieve the same result with the second solution...

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean opeations to get and set the individual values.

It's unclear which bits of your octets apply to which values but you only need `&` (bitwise AND), `|` (bitwise OR), `<<` (left shift) and `>>` (right shift) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Start from writing a packing/unpacking functions for your 2-byte hybrids.

If you so the work with C/C++ - you may use the intrinsic support for this:

```
struct Int3 {
    int a : 3;
    int b : 4;
    int c : 3;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitfields could be one option.  You may need to pad your struct to get the bits to line up the way you want them to.

Refer to [Bitfields in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429802/bitfields-in-c) or search StackOverflow for C++ and bitfields or you can use bitwise operators as outline in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, if we "concatenate" octets as octet2.octet1, we will get 000000[111][1111][111]?

Then you may use bit operations:

- ">>" and "<<" to shift bits in your value,
- "&" to mask bits
- "+" to combine values

For example, "middle" value (which is 4-bits-length) may be received in the following way:

```
middle = 15 & (octet1 >> 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
assert(CHAR_BIT == 8);
unsigned int twooctets = (octet2 << 8) | (octet1); /* thanks, Jonas */
unsigned int bits0to2 = (twooctets & /* 0b0000_0000_0111 */ 0x007) >> 0;
unsigned int bits3to6 = (twooctets & /* 0b0000_0111_1000 */ 0x078) >> 3;
unsigned int bits7to9 = (twooctets & /* 0b0011_1000_0000 */ 0x380) >> 7;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first & be an |?